# Wilks.test usage in R

Tags: r, manova, data-preprocessing

I want to calculate the [Wilks' lambda](https://www.statisticshowto.com/wilks-lambda/) for a given data set. The "rrcov" library in R appears to have a [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rrcov/versions/1.5-2/topics/Wilks.test) for this purpose. The examples provided in the documentation run without a problem; however, I can't get it to work for my own dataset. Here is the piece of code I am using

```
mydata = read.csv(path)
grp <- as.factor(mydata$Label)
x <- as.matrix(mydata[,2:11])
Wilks.test(x, grouping=grp, method="c")
```

The data I am using can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1esOpvtcJmffxZ5I5kjd8AeRg8euXkQXr/view?usp=sharing). The column "label" is my outcome measure which is categorical data, and the rest are my independent variables. I get the following error:

> Error in cov.wt(x[which(grouping == lev[i]), ], wt =
>   wts[which(grouping ==  :    'x' must be a matrix or a data frame

I may be missing something simple in terms of data preparation. I would appreciate it if you could help me with a clue to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the input, but rather you need to ensure all the groups have > 1 observations. At some point when it's calculating the covariance, if there is only 1 observation it becomes quite a problem (rightfully so).

Using the sample.csv you provided (only 6 columns):

```
mydata = read.csv("sample.csv")
Wilks.test(mydata[,-1],factor(mydata$Label))

Error in cov.wt(x[which(grouping == lev[i]), ], wt = wts[which(grouping ==  : 
  'x' must be a matrix or a data frame

table(mydata$Label)

  0   1   2   3   4 
137  36   5   6   1 

mydata = droplevels(mydata[mydata$Label!=4,])
Wilks.test(mydata[,-1],factor(mydata$Label))

    One-way MANOVA (Bartlett Chi2)

data:  x
Wilks' Lambda = 0.74373, Chi2-Value = 52.702, DF = 18.000, p-value =
2.917e-05
sample estimates:
         x1        x2       x3          x4       x5       x6
0 0.8987409 0.6934307 402110.9 0.003270599 24.27494 16.46528
1 1.4864278 1.5833333 322192.4 0.003641968 22.93981 15.81663
2 1.2616600 1.4000000 263894.4 0.005639256 24.00000 16.08754
3 5.1939833 2.6666667 180580.9 0.003105341 22.86111 15.64774
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply @StupidWolf. Unfortunately, I have only 1 data point for category 4. Is there any way around this? I could perhaps integrate categories 3 and 4 into one, but is there any way to get around it? Perhaps just by using ANOVA I can still show examine the null hypothesis that the mean across groups are equal? any recommendations?

Comment: you can't do anova for a group n=1.. merging 3 and 4 is ok